# Image of $4 \times 4$ matrix which maps to the unit disk

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm considering a unit disk embedded in $\mathbb R^4$:$$B^2 := \left \{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\
0 \\
x \\
y \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^4: x^2+y^2 \leq1 \right \}$$ and all linear transformation $T:B^2 \to B^2$ of the form $$T= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\
0& a&0&0\\
0&0&b&0\\
k&m&0&c\end{bmatrix}$$ $a,b,c,k,m \in \mathbb R$. I'm having trouble finding the image of $T$. Clearly $a$ and $m$ are arbitrary as all that is required is that $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\
0& a&0&0\\
0&0&b&0\\
k&m&0&c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\
0 \\
x \\
y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\
0 \\
bx \\
k+cy \end{bmatrix}\in B^2 $$ whenever $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$. Therefore we have that $$b^2x^2+(k+cy)^2 \leq 1$$ for all $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.

It seems that $|bx| \leq |x|$ as taking $x=1$ and $y=0$ we get $b^2+k^2 \leq 1 \implies |b|\leq1$. The $y$ coordinate is not so clear however as taking $x=0$ and $y=1$ we get $(k+c)^2 \leq 1$. Must it be true then that $|k+cy| \leq |y|$? Does anybody see what the image $T$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^4$ by $(u,v,x,y)$. Since $T$ maps the plane $P$ given by $u = 1, v = 0$ to itself, you are reduced to a two-dimensional problem of finding the image of the map $T' = T|_{P}$. This map is given by

$$ T' \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} bx \\ k + cy \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ k \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} bx \\ cy \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ k \end{pmatrix} + A\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$

where $A = \operatorname{diag}(b,c)$. This is an affine map because you have a translation by a constant vector $(0,k)$ followed by the action of a linear map $A$. The image of the unit disc under $A$ is an ellipse centered at the origin with orthogonal axes $e_1,e_2$ of (half) length $b,c$ so the image of $T'$ is an ellipse centered at $(0,k)$ with the same axes and the same lengths.

From this description you can derive conditions on the parameters which guarantee that the image will be inside the unit disc. For example, the center of the ellipse must land inside unit disc so we must have $k \leq 1$. Also, the axes must be inside the unit disc so we must have $|b| \leq \sqrt{1 - k^2}$ and $-1 + c \leq k \leq 1 - c$, etc.

For example, the following image shows the image of the unit disc under $T$ in the $P$ plane with the parameters $k=0.3, b = 0.4, c = 0.2$:

[image]

You can play with the graph and change the parameters on this [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1dp0gsz7ol).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! One more thing is unclear to me, if I have two vectors $v = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $v'=\begin{bmatrix} x'\\ y' \end{bmatrix}$ in the unit disk, are there conditions to determine if there exists $T'$ such that $T' v=v'$?

Comment: @gene: You can try and deduce conditions from the description above but I expect it to be messy and case dependent. For example, if $x = 0$ and $x' \neq 0$, then clearly there is no such $T'$. If $x = x' = 0$ then I expect it to be possible if both $|y|, |y'| < 1$, etc.